# TThreadPoolServer Clients org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

Tags: java, thrift

I am encountering an issue when the thrift client is tested with high load.

Setup:
Thrift Server is a TThreadPoolServer. It performs and operation which takes only 1 -5 ms.Thrift Client connects to the server with a new connection each time, calls the operation once and closes the connection.

When the load is at 160 TPS, the client starts to throw the following exception

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe  at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.flush(TIOStreamTransport.java:161) ~[libthrift-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:65) ~[libthrift-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.ebay.traffic.email.delstats.thrift.interfaces.GSCassandreServices$Client.send_insertRow(GSCassandreServices.java:84) ~[GSCassandreServices$Client.class:na]
at com.ebay.traffic.email.delstats.thrift.interfaces.GSCassandreServices$Client.insertRow(GSCassandreServices.java:75) ~[GSCassandreServices$Client.class:na]
at com.ebay.traffic.email.delstats.thrift.impl.client.SimpleThriftClient.insertRowViaCQL(SimpleThriftClient.java:90) ~[SimpleThriftClient.class:na]
at com.ebay.traffic.email.delstats.entity.EventsEntityQueryHandlerImpl.insertEvents(EventsEntityQueryHandlerImpl.java:97) [EventsEntityQueryHandlerImpl.class:na]
at com.ebay.app.raptor.delstats.resources.StatsServiceResource.registerEvents(StatsServiceResource.java:306) [StatsServiceResource.class:na]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:602) ~[na:2.6 (08-23-2013)]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
```

Please note that connections succeed mostly, but I lose around 10% total connections due to this error

I checked netstat on the server and the connections are getting closed for every single request(Not many open connections at a time) and also there are no exceptions/errors on the server at all. Is this a limitation on the thrift server?

Thanks,
Gopi

Comment: Don't open a new connection each time, try to share or re-use them.

Comment: Server is like a middle ware which will serve around 30 client machines. If I re use connection, then if each machine has 40 threads and the connection is reused, then there will be around 1200 threads open in the server. Is that fine from server perspective?

Comment: It's nothing to worry about, but the question doesn't make sense anyway. If you plan to service 1200 clients simultaneously, that's how many threads you will need, regardless of the connection model. What connection pooling does for you is reduce the number of thread *creations.*

Answer (score 0):

My load opened lot of connections on the server which was more that desired. I could see more than 5000 sockets opened in the server side at a moment. As EJP suggested, the best way to do deal with this is to use a thread pooled client which worked from me. This restricts the connections to the server and the server was able to accept all the connections.

Ways to reproduce the issue:

- Have a Thrift interface which does nothing
- Start TThreadPoolServer
- Run a  simple Java client with 100 threads and each of this client has a for loop running indefinitely - The For Loop should create a new socket, call the thrift interface and then close the socket connection(before the end of loop)